# How to use verifyText() command in selenium using xpath?

Tags: xpath, selenium

I've following XPath of an element and want to extract text using verifyText() command in selenium.

Full XPATH: **html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td**

Portion of html is shown below, how to get text i.e "A Loading icon will appear when you..." using verifyText() command in selenium?

this text is dynamic and can be changed.

```
<table width="730" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
  <tr>
   <td height="30" colspan="2">
   <strong>A Loading icon will appear when you click "Login" button.</strong>
 In case you do not see such icon, it would mean that you are not using a compatible browser
   </td>
  </tr>
  <form id="form1" method="post" autocomplete="off" action="/Login/Password"/>
  <tr>
  <tr>
  <tr>
  <tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command verifyTextPresent which accepts a pattern to match with the text of the page.

Or if there is only  tag as you have mentioned, you can use verifyText("//td","Message to verified")